# Is there a definitive source that explains the reason for the lost primarchs?

Tags: warhammer-40k

While most Legions are heavily featured in the Horus Heresy series, the Legions II and XI aren't really mentioned that much. There's an [ongoing discussion](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Two_unknown_legions#Ultramarines_Codex) about those Legions, with the general consensus, that Games Workshop decided to leave them out on purpose. Seemingly, this is so that players may create their own custom Legions.
For this, however, I couldn't find any definitive proof or any reliable source. Did Games Workshop ever speak out regarding those two Legions?

Comment: I recall a theory that one of the lost primarchs ended up being a major character (the equivalent of the Emperor) from the Warhammer Fantasy line (which is supposed to take place on a planet lost out there somewhere in the 40k universe)

Comment: @evilsoup: My research indicates that the connection between WHFB and WF40k was cut some time ago. If you mean Sigmar, then that's even more unlikely, because he was born by a woman (unlike the primarchs).

Comment: Are you looking for an official reason Games Workshop has left what happened to them vague, or anything that we know happened to them from cannon?

Comment: I'm looking for an official statement _why_ Games Workshop never mentioned those Legions (although I'm aware of several hints in canon).

Comment: I've looked into this myself for a long time and GW have never given an official reason as to what happened to the two legions and why it happened. The wikia page on the [Lost Primarchs](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Primarchs) contains all the hints dropped in conversations throughout the Heresy, but no official GW statement.

Answer (score 4):

I have been reading White Dwarf since issue 62 and still have my Codex Space Marines 2nd and 3rd issue and as far as I can remember no reason was ever given.

Comment: I also think that GW do not want to talk about it. Same discussion about "the Emporer´s healing wounds" was hot some years ago but without GW statements its only "Fanboys wildest dreams".